# Why a*b/c instead of a*(b/c) gives 3x bigger program size on AVR?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, avr, atmega

Recently I tried to pack my code into small ATTiny13 with 1kB of flash. In optimalisation process I discovered something weird for me. Let's take the example code:

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

int main() {
    TCNT0 = TCNT0 * F_CPU / 58000;
}
```

It has no sense of course, but interesting thing is output size - it produces **248 bytes**.

*Quick explaination of code*: `F_CPU` is constant defined by `-DF_CPU=...` switch for `avr-gcc`, `TCNT0` is 8-bit register (on ATTiny13). In real program I assign equation result to *uint16_t*, but still same behaviour was observed.

If part of expression were wrapped in brackets:

```
TCNT0 = TCNT0 * (F_CPU / 58000);
```

Output file size is **70 bytes**. Huge difference, but results of these operations are same (right?).

I looked into generated assembly code and, despite fact that I don't understand ASM very well, I see that no-brackets version adds some labels like:

```
00000078 <__divmodsi4>:
  78:   05 2e           mov r0, r21
  7a:   97 fb           bst r25, 7
  7c:   16 f4           brtc    .+4         ; 0x82 <__divmodsi4+0xa>
  7e:   00 94           com r0
  80:   0f d0           rcall   .+30        ; 0xa0 <__negsi2>
  82:   57 fd           sbrc    r21, 7
  84:   05 d0           rcall   .+10        ; 0x90 <__divmodsi4_neg2>
  86:   14 d0           rcall   .+40        ; 0xb0 <__udivmodsi4>
  88:   07 fc           sbrc    r0, 7
  8a:   02 d0           rcall   .+4         ; 0x90 <__divmodsi4_neg2>
  8c:   46 f4           brtc    .+16        ; 0x9e <__divmodsi4_exit>
  8e:   08 c0           rjmp    .+16        ; 0xa0 <__negsi2>
```

And much more. I learned only x86 assembler awhile, but as far as I remember, for division there was simple mnemonic. Why `avr-gcc` adds so much code in first example?

Another question is why compiler does not inline right part of equation if both numbers are known in compile time.

Comment: These two expressions are not the same. If `F_CPU` is a compile time constant, then `F_CPU / 58000` is also a compile time constant, which results in a single multiplication.

Comment: What is `F_CPU`? A constant or a variable or something else?

Comment: `F_CPU` is constant defined in top of the file or by switch `-DF_CPU=...` for avr-gcc

Comment: What is the _value_ of `F_CPU`?

Comment: It's unsigned long, in this example I used 1200000 passed via flag to compiler

Comment: Thanks  UV.  What is the value  of `TCNT0`?

Comment: @aso please put __all__ relevant information into the question, especially the values of `TCNT0` and `F_CPU ` and how exactly they are defined that trigger the problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky they are AVR-specific, for example F_CPU is defined in compile time (depends of clock speed of target CPU) and TCNT0 is timer register

Comment: @aso but please show the __specific__ values that trigger the problem. [Edit] the question.

Comment: @aso: presuming that this cpu is 32-bit, the first expression will overflow if `TCNT0` is larger than 1789. That's presuming `TCNT0` is 16-bit and will be promoted to a signed 32-bit integer. The second expression might work correctly, if you are not bothered by the fact that `1200000/58000` is not a nice round integer.

Comment: `TCNT0 = TCNT0 * F_CPU / 58000` and `TCNT0 = (TCNT0 * F_CPU) / 58000` are two very different expressions.

Comment: @Jabberwocky First of all, expression with brackets is `TCNT0 * (F_CPU / 58000)` and F_CPU is known at compile time. Question is, why compiler does not inline part of this equation, and if can't - why it adds so much asm code? Does AVR processors need special code for basic math like that? I know that they are 8-bit, but still - amount of generated code is huge.

Comment: @Groo how much result of second expression will differ than first? 1, as integer cuts floating point part instead of rounding, or more, depending of values?

Comment: @aso: the C programming language is pretty clear on the order of operations and required integer promotion. `ATTin13` is an 8-bit controller, meaning that a 32-bit division will take a lot of cycles. And you are forcing 32-bit division by multiplying the value with `F_CPU`.

Comment: @aso you didn't show the assembly code for both versions. And what is the value of `F_CPU`  in your case ?

Comment: @Groo: AVR is an 8-bit RISC microcontroller ISA.  Lots of registers, but they're only 8 bits each.  That's why it takes multiple registers to pass 16-bit `int` or 32-bit `long` args to the mul and div helper functions.  (`int` is the 16-bit minimum that C requires, but `1200000` has type `long` because it's too large for `int`.)   Godbolt has gcc for AVR installed.  https://godbolt.org/z/JF9wq2 shows the optimized asm for `-O3 -mmcu=attiny13`.  (It inlines the multiply as shifts/add in the `foo *= (x/y)` case with a small compile time constant multiplier.)

Comment: @aso: try it yourself, `floor(50*1200000/58000) == 1034`, but `50*floor(1200000/58000) == 1000`.

Comment: @PeterCordes so, as far as I understood, if I wrap right part in brackets compiler will inline result, which produces 8-bit value, and multiplication will be executed on two 8-bit registers, but if there is no brackets all values will be treatened like 16 or 32 bit values and that's why additional code is generated, because 8-bit CPU can't easily perform mul/div operations on >8 bit variables. Right?

Comment: `val *= (F_CPU / 58000)` inlines the multiply as some shift and add instructions, and optimizes it down to 8-bit precision because you're only using 8 bits of the final result.  But in the other way, there's a 32-bit input to a division and the result of division does depend on high bits of the inputs.  So it can't truncate early, and has to respect the C integer promotion rules.  (i.e. that `1200000` is large enough that it has type `long`, so the result is a `long`.)

Comment: aso, please post the _value_ and type of `TCNT0` when `TCNT0 * F_CPU / 58000` is executed.

Comment: The AVR is a very simple processor. It doesn't know how to multiply or divide. You have to *write a function* to multiply and divide numbers on this processor! Luckily, the compiler can do it for you. The compiler people wrote the function already and the compiler just adds it into your code when needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have this:

```
x = x * 1200000 / 58000
```

Note that `1200000/58000 = 20.69...` is not an integer, so this must be computed as first multiplying and then flooring dividing. Your architecture does not have native integer division for this data type, so it has to emulate it, resulting in a lot of code.

However this:

```
x = x * (1200000 / 58000)
```

we find that `1200000 / 58000 = 20`, **since C uses flooring division**, so this code is simplified to just:

```
x = x * 20
```

Comment: ... and `x *= 20` is simple enough for the compiler to inline as some shifts and adds, so the libgcc helper functions don't have to get linked into the binary.  And it only needs to compute it at 8-bit width, never calculating the high half of the `int` result, because it knows it's about to truncate to 8 bit.  (But division results depend on high bits of the inputs so this optimization isn't possible).  https://godbolt.org/z/JF9wq2 shows the optimized asm for AVR gcc9.2 `-O3 -mmcu=attiny13`.

Comment: "since C uses flooring division" --> not quite.  Since C99, division truncates the fraction (toward 0), not floored (toward -inf).  Same when quotient is positive, yet different when negative.  IAC, OP reports `F_CPU` is unsigned long, so the division is certainly a positive one.